# Binding Command to loaded viewmodel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a section in my `MainMenuView` that loads a selected viewmodel in a `ContentControl`. The `DataContext` of the `MainMenuView` is `MainMenuViewModel`.

Can I bind a button from the main menu to a command at the `SelectedViewModel` or do I have to raise an event?

```
<Fluent:Ribbon>
   <!--Userdata-->
   <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Data" x:Name="TabVerm" Group="{Binding ElementName=VermittlerGroup}">
      <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Data">
         <Fluent:Button" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.VermittlerSave, ElementName=VermittlerView}" Header="Save" LargeIcon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=SaveRegular,Width=30,Height=25}"></Fluent:Button>
         <Fluent:Button Header="Cancel" LargeIcon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=UndoAltSolid,Width=30,Height=25}"></Fluent:Button>
      </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
      <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Activate">
         <Fluent:Button Header="Aktivate User" LargeIcon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=StackExchangeBrands,Width=30,Height=25}"></Fluent:Button>
         <Fluent:Button  Header="New User" LargeIcon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=PlusCircleSolid,Width=30,Height=25}"></Fluent:Button>
      </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
   </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
</Fluent:Ribbon>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
   <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by giving your `ContentControl` a name.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
```

Then you can refer to it and its `Content` property that holds the view model in the command binding, e.g.:

```
<Fluent:Button" Command="{Binding Content.VermittlerSave, ElementName=MyContentControl}" Header="Save" LargeIcon="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=SaveRegular,Width=30,Height=25}"/>
```

Of course, this is only applicable, if any selected view model contains the bound command.

Alternatives to binding are communicating with events, e.g. using the [event aggregator pattern](http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/2015/08/16/wpf-event-aggregates.html) that most MVVM frameworks like *Caliburn.Micro* or *Prism* provide or you can have a look at Prism's [`CompositeCommand`](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/composite-commands.html) approach, which allows you to create a command that other commands can attach to. You could create composite commands for your menu and dynamically attach or detach the *real* commands from the selected view model.